# Redirecting all subfolders to URL with GET parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Quick question for redirecting rules. I'm making a url shortener service and I'd like to have all my links from:

http://www.shortener/url

to :
http://www.shortener/index.php?p=url

I tried on my OVH .htaccess the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this does not work, I tried with removing the "/":

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I have a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error on my page.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are seeing error because you have infinite loop occurred there, so we need to place a condition there. Could you please try following, based on your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: JS/CS rewrite/redirect: You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: Well, that gives me a HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @JulienSullivan, are you having exactly same rules in your htaccess file? Or you have any additional rules too in your file? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: This actually is my whole htaccess:

`RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]`

Comment: @JulienSullivan, could you please do give an example of your URL which you are hitting and getting error please.

Comment: Finally got it working with your code, thanks ;)